# How to specify an API key name in Excel - A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, odata, powerbi, odatacontroller

I have a standard `MVC API OData enabled service` which works under anonymous authentication. I would like to pass a web API key to the application...which works fine when added through code or postman..

Unfortunately my users would prefer to use `Excel` and I can't I find anywhere in Excel to enter this data...

I've checked `Fiddler` and  `Excel` is not even trying to send data to the client and I am trapped in one of the errors below.

What is a valid key in Excel and how do it enter it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, open the Power Query Editor, and insert the code below, or adjust the default code: add ApiKeyName = "ApiKey" as part of the 3 parameter of OData.Feed.

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://localhost/odata", null, [Implementation="2.0", ApiKeyName = "ApiKey"]),
    Table_table = Source{[Name="Table",Signature="table"]}[Data]
in
    Table_table
```

Now, you can use the Web API credentials dialog. Your key will be part part of the http query string that is sent to the server: ?ApiKey=abcdefg

See also [authenticating with Excel Power Query against .Net Odata Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225590/authenticating-with-excel-power-query-against-net-odata-web-api)

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain how to do the same thing if the API token must be passed as a header?  I have tried `[Headers=[ApiKeyName="Authorization"]]` but I get the same error as the OP.